# Find an equivalent of sequence at infinity

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

I want to find an equivalent at infinity to those two sequences and then deduce their possible limits:
$$
u_n=\frac{(-1)^n+1}{n+\sqrt{n}},\,v_n=\frac{n^5+e^n}{2n+e^n}.
$$
For the first one, I found, using $n\sim \sqrt{n}$ that 
$$
u_n\sim \frac{(-1)^n+1}{2n},
$$
and I use then  the fact that both $u_{2p}$ and $u_{2p+1}$ converge to zero to obtain that $u_n$ converges also to zero. Can we find a more elegant equivalent of $u_n$ at infinity?
For the second, we already know that 
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}n^a\,e^{-b\,n}=0, a>0,b>o
$$
so the limit of the second sequence $v_n$ is $1$ if we divide both the numerator and the denominator by $e^n$. But, how can we find an equivalent $w_n$ of $v_n$ such that $w_n$ converges to the value $1$ at the infinity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$u_n=\frac{(-1)^n+1}{n+\sqrt{n}}\\0 \leq u_n \leq \frac{1+1}{n+\sqrt{n}} \leq \frac{2}{\sqrt{n}+\sqrt{n}}\\ 0\leq u_n \leq \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} $$when $n \rightarrow \infty $ $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \rightarrow  0 \\ \rightarrow  u_n \rightarrow 0 $$

Comment: for the second one ,find : $u_n  -1+1\\ u_n-1+1=\frac{n^5+e^n}{2n+e^n}$ $$u_n-1+1=\frac{n^5+e^n-2n-e^n}{2n+e^n}+1=\\\frac{n^5-2n}{2n+e^n}+1$$

Comment: I want to find an equivalent sequence $w_n$ of $u_n$ at $+\infty$ (i.e. $u_n\sim w_n$), such that $w_n$ has the limit $0$... Same thing for the second sequence $v_n$.

Comment: you can get $w_n=\frac{n^5}{e^n}+1 ∼ u_n$

Comment: How did you obtain this? I want, if it is possible, to find an equivalent without using $\lim_{n\rightarrow +\infty}n^a\,e^{-bn}=0$, $a>0$, $b>0$...

Comment: note that : $n \rightarrow \infty \\ n^5-2n∼n^5\\2n+e^n ∼ e^n $

Comment: How do you prove the second affirmation?

Comment: $$e^n=1+n+\frac{n^2}{2!}+\frac{n^3}{3!}+\frac{n^4}{4!}+...\\2n+e^n=1+3n+\frac{n^2}{2!}+\frac{n^3}{3!}+\frac{n^4}{4!}+...\\$$for large "n" $$\frac{n^2}{2!} >> 3n \\$$so $$2n+e^n ∼ e^n$$